# Are there continuous functions that satisfies these?

Tags: real-analysis

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x) \notin \mathbb{Q}$  for $ x \in \mathbb{Q}$

$f(x) \in \mathbb Q $ for $x \notin \mathbb{Q} $

I was making cases but couldnot get to anything

Comment: For sure this function cannot be Lipschitz because of measure theory argument but there are continuous functions such that the image of a set of measure zero is nonzero. Therefore measure theory won't help us here :(

Comment: @JanOlszewski im not that advanced either. its just first course in analysis

Comment: Hint: The image of such a function would be at most countable infinite. Why is this a contradiction? (think of something similar to your previous question)

Comment: @Mark why is image of such function be atmost countable infinite ?

Comment: @SophieClad The image of the irrationals is contained in $\mathbb{Q}$, and so countable. The image of the rationals is surely countable, because any function would satisfy $|f(\mathbb{Q})|\leq |\mathbb{Q}|$.